# Make assignment within if-statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have the following problem

in my app i have severeal if-statements

```
 if ( (number >= 1 && number <= 18) && !strcmp("half1-18", _myBetCh) ) {

 }
```

Now I realized that I have to split this condition because I need a boolean variable after one condition

```
  bool success = false, 
  if(!strcmp("half1-18", _myBetCh) {
      success = true; 
      if (number >= 1 && number <= 18) {

      }
  }
```

Is there a workaround to this? Is it possible, for instance, to make an assignment withing the if-statement?

Comment: Assignment is an expression, and like any other expression it can be used as parts of other expressions.

Comment: I dont understand the problem. You can just wrap it in a function that returns the bool?

Comment: Whatever is it that you want to do, don't do it. Your code will be much harder to read, understand and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is:

```
if ( !strcmp("half1-18", _myBatCh) && (success = true, number > 1 && number < 18) )
```

or, obviating the need for the `success = false` earlier

```
if ( (success = !strcmp("half1-18", _myBatCh)) && number > 1 && number < 18 )
```

Your way is easier to read though, so I would consider sticking with what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, like this:

```
if ((success = !strcmp("half1-18", _myBatCh)) && number > 1 && number < 18)
```

but I personally think assignments in conditions are messy and hard to read, and prefer this variation:

```
bool success = strcmp("half1-18", _myBetCh) == 0;  
if (success && number >= 1 && number <= 18) {
    // ...
}
```